# How to load external files in Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm new in Java EE and I'm sorry if I'm posting a stupid question.

I'd like to load/open an external generic file (xml, txt ...) from my EJB since I've to parse it at runtime form my businnes and it can be changed from the "administrator".

How can I implement it in the best Java EE way?

Answer (score 0):

Put your external files in resources folder of project.

Then you can use this code to parse your files

```
InputStream inputStream  = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourfile.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(inputStream);
```

According to your file format, parsing will be change.
For example if it is XML file you can use XML Dom Parser.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'd like to put my files outside the project if is it possible. Is there a way after deploying my EJB to the application server (JBoss) to load an external file?

Comment: Yes sure, you can reach the files out of your project.
Try this;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("../file.txt")));
this path will look exactly out of your project folder.Or you can say "../externalfiles/file.txt" . Path depends on your choice

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `external` directory to the application `classpath`, then you can use either

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("config.xml");
```

or

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.xml");
```